# Embedding multiple YouTube videos on a single page

Tags: asp.net, iframe, youtube

I am attempting to embed 2 separate YouTube videos on an aspx page, but nothing after the first iFrame renders.  I'm relatively new to asp.net - so I apologize if this is a simplistic question - I just can't figure out what the problem is.

Here is the code:

```
        <p class="indent">
        Watch a video showing how to email a report.
    </p>
    <p class="centerText">
        <iframe type="text/html" width="640" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/l8QSqhcnhf8"  allowfullscreen frameborder="0" />
    </p>

    <br />
    <p class="indent">
        Watch a video showing how to create a web page.
    </p>
    <p class="centerText">
        <iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/35yKdLf5B3Y" allowfullscreen frameborder="0" />
    </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to **`<iframe></iframe>`** instead of **`<iframe />`**

```
   <p class="indent">
        Watch a video showing how to email a report.
    </p>
    <p class="centerText">
        <iframe type="text/html" width="640" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/l8QSqhcnhf8"  allowfullscreen frameborder="0" ></iframe>
    </p>

    <br />
    <p class="indent">
        Watch a video showing how to create a web page.
    </p>
    <p class="centerText">
        <iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/35yKdLf5B3Y" allowfullscreen frameborder="0" ></iframe>
    </p>
```